# WIX Custom Actions

Tags: wix

I need to create custom actions in WIX for my MSI. I want to be able to read from a txt,xml or ini file and pass them through into a configuration file.

My problem is I cannot use .net, as the scope for the MSI is to not have any .net interaction and I understand jscript is not a good idea for several reasons.

What options if any do I have left?

Comment: For xml or ini you can use WixUtil functions and if you want to your own custom action you can still use C++ for example

Answer (score 1):

So basically your options:

[Custom c++ actions](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book)

[XML wix Util tool](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/xml)

[Ini wix Util tool](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/inifile.html)